# Authy asks for the recovery password without a reason. Is this normal behavior?

Tags: android, multi-factor

The last time i opened the Authy 2FA app it showed a message telling me to enter my recovery password. The title of the message window was in all-caps and said something along the lines of "Enter your recovery password as a help so you don't forget it". Is this normal behavior or is something sketchy going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, and a sensible idea. If you don't use the password for a year or two, and then suddenly need it, you're quite likely to have forgotten it.